# How can I send email with Amazon SES on Zend Framework - 2.2.1

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, zend-framework2, amazon-ses

I'm using Zend Framework - 2.2.1, and would like to use Amazon SES. For this, I have installed two modules "aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2" and "slm/mail". I have included these two modules in my application.config.php and put aws.local.php in my config/autoload folder and change the Access Key, Secret Key and region in this file.

In the controller file, I created an instance of Mail message class as below:-

```
$objMessage = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
$transport = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SlmMail\Mail\Transport\SesTransport');
$transport->send($objMessage);
```

Its giving me the error "Amazon SES requires exactly one from sender".

Can anyone please suggest on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set sender of your Message instance:

```
$objMessage = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
$objMessage->setFrom('foo@bar.com')
           ->setTo('bar@baz.com')
           ->setSubject('Mail subject');

$transport = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SlmMail\Mail\Transport\SesTransport');
$transport->send($objMessage);
```

Comment: I have tried to use the same but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can any one please suggest on this? How I can achieve the same?